# show same page with different menu item active

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I have these 2 menu and sub-menus for my help manual which has a page leftmenu.php where I have all the menu's and I have included this file above all my pages.

```
<li>
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i> <span class="nav-label">Main menu 1 </span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
        <li><a href="project.php">Project Management</a></li>
        <li><a href="task.php">Task Management</a></li>
        <li><a href="defect.php">Defect Management</a></li>
        <li><a href="customer1.php">Customer Management</a></li>
        <li><a href="user.php">User Management</a></li>
        <li><a href="settings.php">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-ticket"></i> <span class="nav-label">Main menu 2 </span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
        <li><a href="ticket.php">Ticket Management</a></li>
        <li><a href="resolution.php">Resolutions</a></li>
        <li><a href="customer.php">Customer Management</a></li>
        <li><a href="user.php">User Management</a></li>
        <li><a href="settings.php">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Now I have this one customer.php which I would like to use in both the menu's but the menu from where Customer Management is clicked should only be active.
How to I achieve this as I am using only php and html for this.
Thankyou

My code now:

```
<li <?= active('leads|user|settings')?>>
                    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-diamond"></i> <span class="nav-label">Main menu1</span> <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li <?= active('leads') ?>><a href="leads.php">Lead Management</a></li>
                        <li <?= active('user') ?>><a href="user.php">User Management</a></li>
                        <li <?= active('settings') ?>><a href="settings.php">Settings</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li <?= active('project|task|defect|customer1|users|settings1')?>>
                    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i> <span class="nav-label">Main menu2 </span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                      <li <?= active('project') ?>><a href="project.php">Project Management</a></li>
                        <li <?= active('task') ?>><a href="task.php">Task Management</a></li>
                        <li <?= active('defect') ?>><a href="defect.php">Defect Management</a></li>
                        <li <?= active('customer1') ?>><a href="customer1.php">Customer Management</a></li>
                        <li <?= active('users') ?>><a href="users.php">User Management</a></li>
                        <li <?= active('settings1') ?>><a href="settings1.php">Settings</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

Comment: you mean to say that when user s in `Customer Management ` table the menu must show it active. i'm i right...

Comment: If user clicked on customer management from main menu1 then main menu1 should be active along with customer management. Similarly if customer management is clicked from main menu2 then main menu2 should be active both the files of customer management is same but with different breadcrumbs

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function active($page) {
    if (preg_match("/$page\./",$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])) {
        echo "class=active";
    }
}
```

Example

```
<li><a href=index.php <?= active('index') ?>>Home</a></li>
```

**EDIT:**
And Example for Main Menu 1

```
<a <?= active('project|task|defect|customer1|user|settings') ?> href=""><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i> <span class="nav-label">Main menu 1 </span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
```

Comment: this works for the sub menu like 'customer management' is active but not its parent menu or the main menu

Comment: @deepak then simply place the php function in the main menu and add all the pages in it like `active('project|task|defect|customer1|user|settings')`

Comment: I added this to main menu it is working fine for unique file but when it comes to customer.php then both the main menu's are set active now

Comment: You have `user.php` and `settings.php` twice in both menus why? If you have two different user pages and settings then I'd rename into like `user1.php` and `user2.php` etc then put the page names in the function. Name the other one into `customer2.php` etc, it is up to you.

Comment: I created 2 files user and users still both the main menu's are active?

Comment: I copied your code on my lappy and made files like this and tested it, everything is working fine for me. Show me your updated code please

Comment: updated my question and also added my code to your answer

Comment: ok I see that now, place a `.` after user like `active('leads|user.|settings')` in the first menu (or `\.`)

Comment: Nvm, glad this finaly works. `\.` escapes the dot or else it will match any single character after `user`. it's a token in Regular Expression

Comment: I had to change to  if (preg_match("/($page)\b/",$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])) in order to avoid naming my files as user1 or user2

Comment: The user1 and user2 was just an example. For your matter `\b` and `\.`  do the same thing and the brackets are not needed. `(preg_match("/$page\./",...` https://regex101.com/r/dypX4p/1

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap it in a php if statement like this for each value you want to show

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "my/url/") {
// do something
} else {
// do something else
}
```